# Drop down-list using REST API not showing (does in console log)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, function, api

I am using an api which has names of exercises in it. I want to make a search box with an autocomplete drop down (like suggetions google gives you before finish up what you type) But i want to use the api as results.

I managed to get the readings out of the api.

```
let data;

async function getExercises () {
    let url = 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json'

    while (url) {
        const res = await fetch(url)
        data = await res.json()

        for (const item of data.results) {
            console.log(item.name)
        }


        url = data.next

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        BindControls();
    });

    function BindControls() {

        $('#exercise-search').autocomplete({
            source: data,
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true
        }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the drop down using the api results but cant get it to work.

```
<input id="exercise-search" class="form-control" type="text" name="data">
        p, div, input {
       font: 16px Calibri;
 }
    .ui-autocomplete {
    cursor:pointer;
    height:120px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

these are the libraries i imported:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

the console log in my browser doesnt seem to have any errors.

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/voaf1sLg/.

What it boils down to is that **you do not store those search results anywhere**. I've modified the code for your async function to return the full array with all results (after all those 33 API calls, eh!), then return a fulfilled promise with said auto-complete entries. Modify your code accordingly.

```
async function getEx() {
  let url = 'https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json'
  const array = [];

  while (url) {
    const res = await fetch(url)
    data = await res.json()
    for (const item of data.results) {
        console.log(item.name)
        array.push(item.name);
    }
    url = data.next
  }
  return array;
}
$(function() {
  let tags = [];
  getEx().then(res => {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: res
  });
  });
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see your total result count is 685,its better if we can full those records in one shot. but if its not possible then i just modify your code accordingly using recurssion.

```
var sourcearray = []
var getData = function(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(d) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(sourcearray, d.results);
        if (d.next != null) {
            getData(d.next);
        } else {
            console.log(sourcearray)
            var config={
                minLength: 1,
                source: sourcearray,
                focus: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#suggest").val(ui.item.license_author);
                    return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#suggest").val(ui.item.license_author);
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $("#suggest").autocomplete(config).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                return $("<li>").append("<div>" + item.license_author + "<br>" + item.description + "</div>").appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    })
}
$(function() {
    getData("https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json")
});
```

here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/qopjy758/)